# Extracting only the bullet points after a 'strong' title from a website using python

Tags: python, regex, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to extract only the points listed as bullets under the title 'WHAT RESPONDENTS ARE SAYING …' in this [webpage](https://www.instituteforsupplymanagement.org/about/MediaRoom/newsreleasedetail.cfm?ItemNumber=30655).

I am able to achieve it with this code:

```
import requests
URL = 'https://www.instituteforsupplymanagement.org/about/MediaRoom/newsreleasedetail.cfm?ItemNumber=30655&SSO=1'

r = requests.get(URL)
page = r.text
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

strong_el = soup.find('strong',text='WHAT RESPONDENTS ARE SAYING …')
strong_el.find_all_next('li')[9]
```

But the problem here is that I have to know how many bullet points are listed (There are 10 in this case. Hence, it returns valid values until [9]). What is the best way extract all of the bullet points even without knowing how many of them are listed? Also, I need only the text and not the html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`find_next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) to get the `ul` element next to `strong` which contains these `li` elements. Then get all the children of `ul` which are `li` elements:

```
ul_tag = strong_el.find_next_sibling('ul')
for li_tag in ul_tag.children:
    print li_tag.string
```

Comment: I believe you want to change `print li_tag.text` to `print li_tag.string` to get the text w/o the `<li>` tags around it.  As it is now, it will raise an `AttributeError`

Answer (score 1):

you should find the `ul` tag first, it contains all the `li` tags

```
In [3]: ul = strong_el.find_next('ul')

In [4]: for li in ul.find_all('li'):
   ...:     print(li.text)
```

out:

```
“Demand very steady to start the year.” (Chemical Products)
“January revenue target slightly lower following a big December shipment month.” (Computer & Electronic Products)
```